# Java Collections List : Converting from List '<Column <String1, String2>>' to 'List <String1>'

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, jakarta-ee

I have a function that returns a list like this:-

`List  <Column <String1, String2>>`

Next I want to pass this list to a 2nd function, but
2nd function just needs a list which contains only 1st part (string1) of the Column(s) of the above list.

So I want pass just this list to 2nd function:-

`List <String1>`

**my use case**: Both the functions are from a library that I use to access database(Cassandra) for a web application. 1st function gives me a list of all columns which has two parts name(String1) and value(String2). So 1st function gives me a list of all columns(each of which has two strings) then I just need to use the list of column names to supply it to 2nd function that'll query the DB for those columns.

**Since I need to do this job atleast 2-3 times before asking for data from DB for a single page, I need a superfast and a reasonably efficient method to do so.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "efficient" (memory, execution time, something else?) and what that second function is doing.

If you care about speed and the second function is going to be looking at the items in the list repeatedly, then you should probably just copy the strings into a new `List<String>`:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(input.size());
for (Column<String, String> column : input) {
    strings.add(column.name());
}
return strings;
```

If, on the other hand, the second function is going to only look at a small subset of the items or if you care more about memory than speed then you probably want a lazy view that converts items as they are accessed. [`Lists.transform`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) from Google Guava can do this for you:

```
return Lists.transform(input, new Function<Column<String, String>, String>() {
    public String apply(Column<String, String> column) {
        return column.name();
    }
};
```

Note that you may want to create he Function as a separate static class unless you're ok with it holding onto a reference to your enclosing instance. I used an anonymous class here for brevity/clarity.

Comment: @Marcos: From your update it sounds like these lists aren't going to be very long, so I don't know why you're so concerned about efficiency. In any case, you still haven't said whether you care more about memory or speed. If your lists are large then the lazy approach would be better memory-wise. Speed-wise it's hard to say. I'd guess the non-lazy approach would be faster as there'd be fewer method invocations, but the only way to know for sure is to measure. JIT optimizers can be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no simpler way than simply walking over the first list and ask each `Column` for its `String1` and then add that value to your `List<String1>`.

If you want to separate the walking and the adding, then consider writing an Iterator which returns all the String1's from the first list, and then use traverse that.

Answer (score -1):

In Scala, you could just do:

```
stringsList = columnsList.map(_.string2)
```